# How to get Google Ads Keywords and Ad Contents via Google Analytics API

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-ads-api

I need AdWords data from Goole Analytics API.

Please tell me what is collect queries for dimensions and filter.

For example;

Traffic > Acquisition > Adwords > Campaigns

I could get data using the following queries.

Dimensions
ga:campaign,ga:adwordsCampaignID

Filters
ga:adwordsCampaignID!=(not set)

How about below?

Traffic > Acquisition > Adwords > Keywords  Primary Dimension: Keyword

Traffic > Acquisition > Adwords > Keywords  Primary Dimension: Ad Content

How can I get these data from GA API?

Referrer
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=adwords

Comment: how much did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

**Both the Ad content and Keyword dimensions are derived from `utm_` parameters, so you will find them under the traffic sources section** (note: these `utm_` parameters are auto-tagged by AdWords):

- Ad Content: [`ga:adContent`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=traffic_sources&jump=ga_adcontent) (derived from `utm_content`)
- Ad Keyword: [`ga:keyword`](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets#view=detail&group=traffic_sources&jump=ga_keyword) (derived from `utm_term`)

Comment: I have tried using ga:adContent and ga:keyword on Query Explorer,
but the data does not match between GA UI and Query Explorer.

Does it need to add some filter?

Comment: the UI and API should display the same results as long as the queries are identical.